# Разные DNS выдают разные IP адреса на один и тот же домен, почему?

Tags: сеть, ip, dns, домен

Заметил такой нюанс, когда пытаюсь узнать IP адрес сайта через nslookup **uapa.ru** используя DNS провайдера, то получаю вот такой **IP: 172.16.0.8.**
А когда использую DNS от гугла, т.е. nslookup uapa.ru 8.8.8.8, то получаю вот такой **IP:213.242.253.81** . **Подскажите, пожалуйста, из-за чего DNS выдают разные IP адреса для одного и того же домена?**

Comment: У вас там точно не round robin? )

Comment: @Suvitruf round robin с адресами из разных подсетей? Оригинально.

Comment: Могу предположить, что провайдер по какой-то причине проксирует трафик. Если это - правда (что на данном этапе далеко не факт, да и проксировать клиентов - дело дорогое), то провайдера необходимо нахлобучить всеми доступными средствами.

Comment: @Etki балансить можно и между датацентрами. В чём проблема?

Comment: @Suvitruf так никто не делает.

Comment: Да, провадера точно надо нахлобучить, адрес в DNS поменял, а _все_  DNS запросы на свою DNS не завернул, зачем такие полумеры :)

Comment: @Etki Так уж и никто? Как насчет amazon.com?
Я уж не говорю про irc.freenode.net, например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Роунд робин не виноват - адрес один отдаётся.
213.242.253.81 резолвится из нескольких мест вполне успешно и однообразно.
Для начала убедитесь что в файле hosts или на днс серверах локальных случаем не затесалась строчка наподобие

```
172.16.0.8  uapa.ru
```

А потом начинайте ругать техподдержку провайдера.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала стоит ознакомится с основами построения сетей, или хотя бы ознакомится со статьей: [Частный IP-адрес](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_IP-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81).
Судя по всему, у твоего провайдера собственная локальная сеть, в которой используются "серые" IP адреса. И провайдер настроил свой DNS сервер, что бы тот подключенным к локалке выдавал СЕРЫЕ IPы локальных ресурсов, а остальным БЕЛЫЕ. Именно поэтому, когда используешь ресолвер провайдера, ты получаешь серый IP (172.16.0.8), тогда как ресолвер гугля получает белый IP (213.242.253.81), который тебе и отдает.

Comment: Все верно, кроме того, что "серыми" называют внешние IP, которые провайдер разделяет между клиентами. В данном случае 172.16.0.8 - это просто локальный адрес класса B, и провайдер использует его, чтобы оптимизировать трафик, так как сайт по всей видимости находится в локальной сети